# How to create a patch using install4j?

Tags: install4j

I am working on an application that has thousands of files. Installation and configuration takes lots of time. Is it possible to create a patch to replace just a few changed files rather than creating a new installer and installing the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install4j cannot generate the patch for you by comparing two different distribution trees. However, you can assemble the patched files yourself and create an "add-on" installer project. This is configured on the Installer->Update options step.